# What are the Benefits and Limitations of Pair Testing?

Tags: pairwise-testing

Can you give me a brief overview of what pair testing is, along with some of its pros and cons over single person testing.

Comment: What do you think the answer is? What research have you done? Have you listed out the benefits and drawbacks of pair testing? /

Answer (score 2):

Pair Testing :

Pair testing is a collaborative effort, versus a single-person testing effort.  Typically, one of the team members is a tester and the other is either a developer or a business analyst.  Please refer this below link.                   (https://blog.testlodge.com/what-is-pair-testing/)

Advantages:

1. Pair testing helps in indentifying the negative flow in the functionality.
2. It helps to improve better communication with the peers
3. Pair testing helps to save time while testing.
4. It is very helpful to train the peers who are working in the project.
5. Pair Testing can not be done only by testers. It can also be done by Business analysts, Project Managers and Developers also can do.

When to do pair Testing?

1. When we working on an agile environment with 2 or 3 weeks sprint then pair testing will be really helpful to improve the quality of the application.
2. When there is a addition of new resources in the team then when doing pair testing helps to train the new comer

Comment: Please reference your quotes - I found the definition of pair testing you used above on several sites.

Answer (score 1):

What is Pair testing?

**Answer:**

Pairwise testing is a practice where two team members are sitting together to test the software application on the same machine. The team members for pair testing can be a tester- developer, tester-tester, tester-business analyst.

**The Outcome of Pair testing**

- Test documentation
- Defect reports
- Session reports
- Shared knowledge

We can do pair testing with colleagues from my Scrum team on a regular basis. Some sessions are short, minutes to an hour, and some are longer, up to a day. Sometimes it is planned, and sometimes it’s spontaneous.

Why Pair testing?

**Answer:**

- A tester working alone may jump to incorrect conclusions
- Reduces the number of tests to be performed
- To test a specific area of functionality

**Benefits of pair testing**

- Combine testers from different technical backgrounds and hence being
  able to provide different perspectives and approaches to the test.
- Combine testers of different levels of experience
- More interactions with developers and management teams
- Faster bug identification and prevention
- Better feature usability can be achieved.

For more details about pair testing, you can check out

[Pair Testing](https://www.guru99.com/pairwise-testing.html)

[How to perform Pair Testing](https://www.stickyminds.com/article/who-what-when-and-how-pair-testing)